# Get current URL in webview

Tags: android, webview, dart, flutter

I am using [Flutter WebView Plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) to create `webview` in Flutter app.
I have added a `reload` icon inside the `appBar`. In order to make the `reload` icon functional, I want to get the `current URL` from `webview`.

**WebView:**

```
return new MaterialApp(
      theme
        : new ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0), fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
      routes: {
        "/": (_) => new WebviewScaffold(
          url: url,
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: Text(title),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.refresh, color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1.0),),
                onPressed: () => flutterWebviewPlugin.reloadUrl(url), // this is reloading the url that was provided to webview, not the current URL.
              )
            ],
          ),
          withJavascript: true,
          withLocalStorage: true,
          appCacheEnabled: true,
          hidden: true,
          initialChild: Container(
            child: const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          ),
        )
      },
    );
```

Is there any function to get the `current URL` from `webview` or any other method? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it enough for your reload button to use `Future<Null> reload();`? This seems to reload the current url. So you don't have to set the url explicit.

You have to change the call of the function to

```
onPressed: () => flutterWebviewPlugin.reload(), // this is reloading the url that was provided to webview, not the current URL. )
```